# How to detect if bbPress forum index

Tags: conditional-tags, bbpress

I posted a question in bbforum 2 months ago without success, https://bbpress.org/forums/topic/enque-bbpress-scripts-only-on-forum-pages/

I am working on a theme and need to deque all bbpress scripts and enque my own if I am on forum pages. This is what I used to start with

```
if( !is_admin() ){ 
    /**
     *  Replace bbpress style with our own
     *  @internal
     */
    function _thz_action_bbpress_style() {

        wp_dequeue_style( 'bbp-default' );

        if (is_bbpress()){

            wp_enqueue_style( THEME_NAME. '-bbpress' ); 

        }


    }

    if (function_exists('is_bbpress')){
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '_thz_action_bbpress_style' );
    }
```

Just trying to find a conditional that actualy works.

```
is_bbpress()
```

does not work if you have a forum homepage via

```
[bbp-forum-index]
```

shortcode

According to [the docs](https://codex.bbpress.org/bbpress-conditional-tags/) is_bbpress() should detect it but it does not.

Does anyone know a working solution?

I am trying to avoid , `has_shortcode($page_content, 'bbp-forum-index')` since it will have to be used on all pages which in fact kills performance for no reason.

Comment: Try this workaround http://pastebin.com/QLcBVjT7

Comment: @SamuelElh that places the stylesheet at the bottom of the page instead in head

Comment: You can always filter `is_bbpress`, I tried something http://pastebin.com/Eyeqimwt but for early usage (e.g wp is not loaded) it won't work as `$wp_query->queried_object` goes null.